# Не работает Auth (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, auth

Проблема заключается в том что Auth в "Controller" не определяет пользователя авторизованным(даже если пользователь вошел он скажет что это не так), в остальных контроллерах все работает. v 5.5.32.

```
    if(Auth::check()){
        $user_id = Auth::user()->steamid64;
    } else{
        $user_id = '76561197960287332';
    }
```

Comment: Замените пожалуйста картинку кодом как текст.

Comment: Вы это случайно не в конструкторе делаете ? если так, то просто middleware которая отвечает за авторизацию еще не сработала